# Get current timepoint from Totem application

Tags: python, linux, gnome, dbus, totem

I want to find the exact time where a media file is currently paused at (or playing) in a running Totem instance using D-Bus. To be precise, what I want is available from the Totem python console (if the plugin exists and is enabled) by the following command:

```
>>> print totem_object.props.current_time
732616
```

which I understand is milliseconds.

So far:
I've never used D-Bus before, so I'm in the process of going through D-Bus and python-dbus documentation. I've also fired up D-Feet and found that the `org.gnome.Totem` bus name and the `/Factory` object I can use the `org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties` interface methods.

I'm currently at this point:

```
>>> import dbus
>>> seb= dbus.SessionBus()
>>> t= seb.get_object('org.gnome.Totem', '/Factory')
>>> tif= dbus.Interface(t, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
>>> tif.GetAll('')
dbus.Dictionary({}, signature=dbus.Signature('sv'))
```

I can't find even a proper how-to, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm currently researching the the API for a different reason, I need to retrieve the path or location being played, and I stumbled upon this question.

First things first, you'll want to activate the D-Bus Service Plugin (Edit -> Plugins) which will expose the `org.mpris.Totem` service. Then on the `/Player` object and the `org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer` interface you can use the `PositionGet()` method to retrieve the current position.

This returns `totem.props.current_time` you were talking about.

Here's some code:

```
import dbus

T_SERVICE_NAME = "org.mpris.Totem"
T_OBJECT_PATH = "/Player"
T_INTERFACE = "org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer"

session_bus= dbus.SessionBus()

totem = session_bus.get_object(T_SERVICE_NAME, T_OBJECT_PATH)
totem_mediaplayer = dbus.Interface(totem, dbus_interface=T_INTERFACE)

print totem_mediaplayer.PositionGet()
```

As for the whole `org.gnome.Totem` service and the Get/GetAll methods, I don't understand the entire purpose of those either. Looks like it has more to do with DBus itself than Totem specifically.

**References**

1. http://git.gnome.org/browse/totem/tree/src/plugins/dbusservice/dbusservice.py
2. http://developer.gnome.org/totem/stable/TotemObject.html

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly it.

Comment: Thanks @Bruce-van-der-Kooij. Is there a method to add video to playlist ?